# SSH remote tunnel works manually but not as system service

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I have setup remote/reverse tunnel `cloud server <- in-house server` and I can access `http://cloudserver.com:8001` successfully.

In the in-house server I manually execute the following and it works successfully

```
/usr/bin/ssh -N -vvv -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -R 8001:127.0.0.1:80  myuser@cloudserver.com
```

When I set this up as system service (**Ubuntu server with GUI**) the service seems to be running but the tunnel is not established.

my `parking-tunnels.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Parking Tunnels
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=15
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh -N -vvv -i /home/some-user/.ssh/mykey -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -R 8001:127.0.0.1:80 myuser@cloudserver.com
User=some-user
Group=some-group
StandardInput=tty-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
journalctl -u parking-tunnels.service

Apr 21 18:05:06 dcs2 systemd[1]: Stopping Parking Tunnels...
Apr 21 18:05:06 dcs2 systemd[1]: parking-tunnels.service: Succeeded.
Apr 21 18:05:06 dcs2 systemd[1]: Stopped Parking Tunnels.
Apr 21 18:05:06 dcs2 systemd[1]: Started Parking Tunnels.
Apr 21 18:06:13 dcs2 systemd[1]: Stopping Parking Tunnels...
Apr 21 18:06:13 dcs2 systemd[1]: parking-tunnels.service: Succeeded.
Apr 21 18:06:13 dcs2 systemd[1]: Stopped Parking Tunnels.
Apr 21 18:06:13 dcs2 systemd[1]: Started Parking Tunnels.
```

- I have also tried with and without `User=`, `Group=`, with and without ssh options `-f` `-t` `-T` `-g`.
- I have found out that `StandardInput=tty-force` is required, otherwise the service cannot start.
- Also tried `ssh -f` and `Type=forking` but the service won't even load.
- I do not forget to run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
- Cloud server has `GatewayPorts yes`. I have firewall in cloud server but for I have disabled it until I fix this.
- ssh to cloud server does not need credentials because I have shared a key. When executing manually to password is asked I do not know if something is wrong via service.

When service is running I can see it with `ps aux | grep ssh` however the tunnel is not established. And even copy/pasting the command from ps runs successfully.

What is wrong when running as service?

## UPDATE

`StandardInput=tty-force` is transferring all the log from `ssh -vvv` to another tty that is why no log was displayed.

Also only `ssh -N` is required.

I could validate the tunnel because the firewall for the clients (my local pc) was enabled.

*Sorry for the post.* **Thank you all for your help.**

Comment: Since you've already increased the verbosity of ssh, what is the output of the service (`systemctl status tunnels.service` or `journalctl -u tunnels.service`)?

Comment: Presumably `myuser@cloudserver.com` needs to authenticate somehow? I wonder if that is happening via an agent when you execute the command manually, but ssh is hanging waiting for interactive authentication when run as a service? That may also explain why the service fails to start at all without `StandardInput=tty-force`.

Comment: @steeldriver I have shared a key with cloud server. When I manually execute the tunnel to password is asked. I do not know if I have set something in service and there it requires password.

Comment: @Wieland added the info to the question

Comment: The only way I can see this working is if you set up key-based authentication with an empty key *passphrase*. You may also need to pass the identity file (private key) location explicitly using the ssh `-i` option.

Comment: @steeldriver yes, that is what I set up. When manually running the command the -i is not required. I also tried the service command with -i but the error persists.

Comment: Use the -i option for the key file.

Comment: @K-att- I just tried it, the error persists

Comment: +use the -n option too.

Comment: @K-att- still fails

Comment: @Wieland How can I actually get the log from ssh since it is not showing in journalctl even though I have -vvv

Comment: /var/log/auth.log should show you connection attempts (like tunnel connections).  it'll show key errors and other info.

Comment: @Theofanis in the `ExecStart` you're using `-I` as if it were `-i`. They are two different things

Comment: @LL3 sorry just autocorrect, I use `-i`

Comment: @Theofanis what ports are your two servers using for ssh?  if the cloud server isn't running on port 22, you might need to include "-o Port=FOO", replacing FOO with the port it's using.  also, are you able to ssh into the cloud server from the in-house server without a password?